# Difference betwen collectibles items and Assets in Nami Wallet?

Tags: nft, nami-wallet

I had been forging some NFTs, but all my NFTs are listed in the Collectible Part of the Nami Wallet. Even when i followed the 721 standard reported in the CIP-25 for my on-chain metadata. This makes me wonder, what makes the distinction between Assets and Collectibles for the Nami-Wallet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks to be the correct behavior - nfts are often considered to be collectible items and used in that way.

I've found [this](https://github.com/Berry-Pool/nami-wallet/blob/24701e1b68c80c90c6f2f50545e6e710095c239f/src/ui/app/pages/wallet.jsx#L176) in nami wallet, it's looking for an nft metadata attached to the asset, thats what makes it to be visible in `Collectibles` tab of Nami.